# Reducing the size of the photo

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm recording the photos taken by my application in the sqlite database, I know it's not very recommended anymore I need to transfer these photos to a central database that unifies all data from all applications.

The way I'm reducing and writing to sqlite bank is this way:

```
 Android.Graphics.Drawables.BitmapDrawable bd = (Android.Graphics.Drawables.BitmapDrawable)imageView.Drawable;
 Bitmap bitmap = bd.Bitmap;
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
 bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
 byte[] ba = stream.ToArray();
 string bal = Base64.EncodeToString(ba, Base64.Default);
```

Personally, I am editing my question because the problem is not in the select as I had thought it could be, but at the time of writing to the database. The code above works great when searching for a photo or image on the device. The problem is when it takes the photo for the application, then I get this error that is below.

I think I need to compress App.bitmap, which gets the shot taken right away. I just do not know how to do it yet. As I said the above code works great with the pictures taken by the device, but when I shoot through my application I get this error.

I'm going to post my OnActivityResult method so that you can help me figure out what this error is.

Error:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Searching on the internet this error is returning because of the size of the cursor that have a maximum of 2MB.

OnActivityResult Method:

```
  protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Make it available in the gallery
        try
        {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.FromFile(App._file);
            mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
            SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

            // Display in ImageView. We will resize the bitmap to fit the display.
            // Loading the full sized image will consume to much memory
            // and cause the application to crash.

            int height = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
            int width = imageView.Height;
            App.bitmap = App._file.Path.LoadAndResizeBitmap(width, height);
            if (App.bitmap != null)
            {
                imageView.SetImageBitmap(App.bitmap);

                // App.bitmap = null;
            }

            // Dispose of the Java side bitmap.
            GC.Collect();

        }
        catch
        {
        }
        try
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                var imageView =
                FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
                imageView.SetImageURI(data.Data);



            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }
```

Without fetching the photo, the select does not return the error quoted above. I'm counting on your help.

Comment: You are not reducing the size of the image at all, at least with the code shown here

Comment: how large is the data that you are actually writing to the db?  Have you actually checked, or are you just making assumptions?

Comment: Why don't you store the photos on the device storage and store a uri to them in sqlite?

Comment: Tyczj This would be the responsible party to reduce! Does not it reduce?  'bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);'

Comment: Hi @Jason, thanks for responding, I checked the bank for this recording!

When I pass the conversation using the
`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource (Resources, Resource.Drawable.img_p);` that's right, but when I use `Bitmap bitmap = (App.bitmap); That's where it goes

Comment: @Samuel thanks for responding. I do not leave in the memory of the device because I have to pass the photos to another server, leaving in the memory of the device also runs the risk of the user deletes the image

Comment: Can you check the size of your "byte[] ba" after your "stream.ToArray()" ?

Comment: @hugo, thanks for replying. Could you tell me how I can do this check

Comment: @RenatoLima just put a breakpoint when you execute your code and check the size of the byte array after the ToArray() execution

Comment: @Hugo, thanks. I'll do this check. The strange thing is when I look in the gallery of the device it works very well, but when I take the photo on the camera of the application I get this error. I'm going to edit my question, why doing the tests and verified that it's not the select, but rather the way I'm recording when I take the picture through the application.

Comment: Personal thank you all for the attention and the attempt to help me, I manage to solve the problem by passing the size of the height and the width to be compacted. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Use EncoderParameter to specify the level of compression for an image.
see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter(v=vs.110).aspx
and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.quality(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Personal thank you all for the attention and the attempt to help me, I manage to solve the problem by passing the size of the height and the width to be compacted. Thank you all